# Updating Progress Bar in a Form from Downloading in a Class

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, progress-bar

I know there have been a lot of questions here but I have went through a ton of them and have had little luck. I'm new to events and background workers and I just don't know the best way to implement this.

I have a a basic Windows form in C#. It contains a progress bar. I am calling a class that is to download a file. I want the progress bar to update based on that download. I have it working fine if everything is all in the same class, but I can't get it to work in this situation. What is the best way to handle this and how might I go about it? Currently I'm doing this:

```
WebClient downloader = new WebClient();             
downloader.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
```

And then for progress changed I do this:

```
public void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pbDownload.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

But when I put all of this except for the progress bar in a separate class, it gets all messed up. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: messed up in what way? Error, not reacting ok, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this witch is about the same as what you are trying to do and works fine
FStatus ... form reference

```
 FrmStatus FStatus = null;

        public void ProgressInit(String caption, string opis, int Max)
        {
            FStatus = new SZOKZZ.FrmStatus();
            FStatus.InitProc(Max);
            FStatus.SetCaption(caption, opis);
            FStatus.Show();
        }

        public void DLProgress(string curl, string cdl)
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DLDone);
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DLSetProc);
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(curl), cdl);
        }
        private void DLSetProc(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._FileProcentDownloaded = e.ProgressPercentage;
            FStatus.SetProcDL(this._FileProcentDownloaded);

        }
        private void DLDone(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _DlError = e.Error;
            FStatus.Dispose();
            FStatus = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call Application.DoEvents(); to force your form to update controls based on their new values :

```
   public void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbDownload.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Regards